# How is it valid syntax in Java to use an assignment operator in a larger arithmetic expression?

Tags: java, assignment-operator, arithmetic-expressions

Context: I'm mainly a Javascript/Python developer and I'm doing Java just for schoolwork.

This is the code block that perplexes me.

```java
public static void display(int a, int b) {
  a = a+b-(b=a);
  System.out.println(a);
  System.out.println(b);
}
```

I encountered this code block in a practice exam I was doing. I expected this to be syntactically incorrect so I tried it with a compiler. No syntax errors appeared.

I don't understand how this is valid syntax. I get that the assignment operator would assign `a` to `b` and the result of `a = a+b-(b=a)` would be the original value of `a`. How does the compiler register `b-(b=a)` as a valid piece of code?

Comment: Why would it not be? An assignment expression is still an expression with a well-defined result - see https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se10/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.26

Comment: `b=a` assigns to `b` and evaluates to the new value of `b`.

Comment: _the result of `a = a+b-(b=a)` would be the original value of a_ - no, the result is `a + b - a` which is equal to the value `b` had before. The whole construct is similar to Python: `a, b = b, a`

Comment: Right, it's just something allowed by the syntax.  It's useful for example when you both want to remember a result of a method call, and calculate with that result too.  `for( int c; (c = stream.read()) != -1; )` etc...

Comment: Short answer: Because James Gosling decided it so. Slightly longer answer: Given Java's heritage as "C family" language, i.e. with syntax similar to C, that decision was understandable. The concept of assignments being expressions with well-defined values was familiar to Java's original target group when it was introduced, i.e. C and C++ programmers, and James Gosling saw no reason to take that away. Guido van Rossum on the other hand had different priorities when designing Python, and familiarity for C/C++ programmers wasn't in his top tier. So there you have it, I guess.